# Get data back after posting files to gridfs with angular-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gridfs, angular-file-upload

I post files from my controller, to my server, where gridfs writes them. After that, there is a writestream.on('close') where I can console.log the file._id to the terminal.

How can I set a variable back in my angular controller to the file._id?
The server doesn't know what angular is, so how can I access it? Also, the angular-file-upload automatically makes the post, so I'm not sure how I could add a callback.

https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the examples for a full list of subscribers. This could be what you're looking for:

```
uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
    console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
};
```

Comment: This can give me stuff about the file, but I want the actual _id back from mongodb from gridfs

Comment: Can I add the _id to the response of one of those callbacks?

Comment: Sure, have a look at "upload.php". You could response anything you want when the stream is closed. All could be like this:
Server: `writestream.on('close', function(file) { res.json({ id: file._id }); });`
Client: `uploader.onCompleteItem = function(file, res) { console.log(res.id); };`